# Ubuntu 18.04 boot fail on video driver

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

To be able to play some games, I got a message saying that I had to upgrade my video driver.
Going into setting, I could NOT select any of the other nVidia driver, than the one installed by default with Ubuntu. So, I went to nVidia site to dowbload the latest drivers.

After downloading and installing the latest nVidia Ubuntu driver from nVidia, I did a reboot to have the new driver working ... Did not work at all (Power off to restart!!)

With a live Ubuntu Stick, I got this in the kernel log:

> Blockquote

***ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu/Ubuntu 18.04 SSD/var/log$*** tail kern.log

Jan 21 15:20:13 Tristram kernel: [   13.040975] NVRM: API mismatch: the client has the version **390.87**, but

Jan 21 15:20:13 Tristram kernel: [   13.040975] NVRM: this kernel module has the version **415.25**.  Please

Jan 21 15:20:13 Tristram kernel: [   13.040975] NVRM: make sure that this kernel module and all NVIDIA driver

Jan 21 15:20:13 Tristram kernel: [   13.040975] NVRM: components have the same version.

***ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu/Ubuntu 18.04 SSD/var/log$***

> Blockquote

Ovbiously, it is the X server that is not upto date! What can I do to correct this problem and Ubuntu be able to boot normally?

Please help me...

RD

System:

MB: Asus Z390-Pro

CPU: Intel I7-8700K & 4.2 Ghz

Ram: PC-3600 16GB (2x8GB)

Video: nVidia GTX-1070ti 8GB

Screen: 3840x1200 (2x1920x1200)

Answer (score 0):

Searching in the logs I found that the nVidia driver package seems to be at fault!
Here is the relevant portion of dpkg.log relative to nVidia:

> Blockquote

ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu/Ubuntu 18.04 SSD/var/log$ **cat dpkg.log | grep nvidia | less**

2019-01-21 14:07:42 install nvidia-settings:amd64  415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1

2019-01-21 14:07:42 status half-installed nvidia-settings:amd64 415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1

2019-01-21 14:07:42 status unpacked nvidia-settings:amd64 415.27-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1

2019-01-21 14:07:42 status **unpacked nvidia-settings:amd64 415.27**-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1

2019-01-21 14:07:42 **configure nvidia-kernel-source-390:amd64 390.87**-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1

2019-01-21 14:07:42 status unpacked nvidia-kernel-source-390:amd64 390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1

2019-01-21 14:07:42 status half-configured nvidia-kernel-source-390:amd64 390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1

2019-01-21 14:07:42 status installed nvidia-kernel-source-390:amd64 390.87-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1

> Blockquote

So the problem might be on nVidia shoulder .... I'll put a msg for their support!

RD